# Manually predict lognormal survreg model considering parameters uncertainty

Tags: r, survival, prediction, censoring

I'm analyzing environmental data using the "NADA" R library, which relies heavily on the "survival" package.
I am dealing with left-censored data, which are nonetheless strictly positive. To deal with the positiveness I'm using a "lognormal" distribution.
As I need to use the developed model in another software I need to be able to do predictions without using the `predict` command. In order to do that I'm using the following pseudo-formula (where Y is the prediction, X are the predictions and intercept, coeff and scale come from the model outcome):

```
Y=10^(intercept+sum(coeff*X)+scale*qlnorm(0.5))
```

The `Y` value is different from the outcome of the `predict` command using the same Xs.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

EDIT: I found that the prediction is calculated, for the quantile of interest, using:

```
Y=exp(intercept+sum(coef*X)+scale*qnorm(quantile))
```

How is it possible to take into account also the standard error in the parameters estimates?
Thanks

Comment: What is `lnorm()`?

Comment: `qlnorm(p)` is the quantile of a lognormal distribution with meanlog=0 and sdlog=1 and p is the percentile. I edited the question since the q was missing

Comment: I'm using `qlnorm`. The typo was just here, not in the actual code

Comment: Yes sorry! I didn't realise you'd already edited the question :)